# Upload de Imagem e guardar no servidor Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Amigos poderiam me ajudar a criar uma função para gravar o caminho + nome da imagem no banco de dados, e guardar a imagem em meu servidor ?

Estou usando o campo `model.PhotoName` que é uma `string` para poder armazenar o caminho, mas não sei como faço o upload para o servidor.

Quero enviar a imagem junto com o formulário de Funcionário.

poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Voce usa banco de dados? Acredito que seria viável guarda-las no banco de dados como base64, mas só pra saber, vou colocar o metodo que uso, para salvar

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer upload de arquivo ao mesmo tempo que enviar um formulario asp.net mvc 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95961/como-fazer-upload-de-arquivo-ao-mesmo-tempo-que-enviar-um-formulario-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Acho que meu problema é diferente, eu quero enviar a minha imagem junto com o formulario, mas quero salva-la em uma pasta em meu servidor, e guardar o caminho + nome no banco de dados

Comment: Edenilson Bila, uso banco sim.